# SQL Converting Access DB null value to blank string

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ms-access, isnull

I am stuck trying to fix this error and have been at it for far too long. I've done a lot of Googleing and searching this site but can't seem to find the right answer for me even though there are many different variations of this question.

I am writing a front end GUI using VB.Net with an Access database on the back end. The DB has NULL values in `PartnerFirstName`, `PartnerLastName`, and `Organization` in my Partner Table. I am loading these into a Datatable in my application so they can be searched by the user. I just found out last week that some partners (the one's with NULL values) are not loading.

Code below:

```
("SELECT IDPartner, IIF(ISNULL(PartnerFirstName),'',PartnerFirstName) as PartnerFirstName, IIF(ISNULL(PartnerLastName), '', PartnerLastName) AS PartnerLastName, IIF(ISNULL(Organization), '', Organization) AS Organization, " & _
        "Address1, City, State, Zip, Country, Active " & _
 "FROM tblPartner " & _
 "WHERE IDPartner like '%" & txtPartnerID.Text & "%' AND " & _
 "      PartnerFirstName like '%" & txtFirstName.Text & "%' AND " & _
 "      PartnerLastName like '%" & txtLastName.Text & "%' AND " & _
 "      Organization like '%" & txtOrganization.Text & "%' AND " & _
 "      Address1 like '%" & txtStreet.Text & "%' AND " & _
 "      City like '%" & txtCity.Text & "%' AND " & _
 "      State like '%" & txtState.Text & "%' AND " & _
 "      Zip like '%" & txtZipCode.Text & "%' AND " & _
 "      Country like '%" & txtCountry.Text & "%' " & _
 "ORDER BY IDPartner, partnerlastname, partnerfirstname", cn)
```

The reason for the `like`s are because I want the search to update in real time based on the form's text box values. This is the source of my problem since they are blanks by default and the DB has nulls.

===================

EDIT:

Thank for the initial comments. I realize now that I was using an improper function. the IIF suggested by Baro gets me through the SQL now which is great!

It appears the issue I'm having with records not showing up is in my WHERE clause. If I remove that then all the records load into my Datatable. When I include the Where clause as shown the records will NULL values are excluded.

I have tried to use an `OR PartnerFirstName IS NULL` (as well as the other fields) but that leaves too many extra results that also have NULL values. I cannot figure out what to do to allow the search now that I know the problem is in the Where section of the statement.

Comment: Is it SQL Server or Access? They are not the same thing. The MSDN article you link is for SQL Server. In Access, the equivalent is the Nz function.

Comment: Try with: IIF(ISNULL(PartnerFirstName),'',PartnerFirstName)... and then correct your first like, you missing an "AND".

Comment: you need to  see that the query is executed against Access; Access has no second parameter for ISNULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for you help and suggestions, I have learned a lot from the few suggestions and really appreciate it!

I have solved the problem by going back into Access. I ran an update query on any NULL field and changed it to a "". Such a simple solution!

If I didn't have the WHERE requirements in place that I do this wouldn't have been such a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `WHERE` predicate is targeting the original field(s), which have not had the `IIF(ISNULL(...))` expression applied. 
It is difficult to see because you've aliased the field in the `SELECT` statement as the same name as the underlying field. So, the query is doing what you've instructed it to do, albeit not what you've meant for it to do.
To resolve, I would use a subquery which converts the `NULL` values to empty strings and then in the outer query add your `WHERE` predicate. Something like the following should do the trick:

```
("SELECT q.* FROM (SELECT IDPartner, IIF(ISNULL(PartnerFirstName),'',PartnerFirstName) as PartnerFirstName, IIF(ISNULL(PartnerLastName), '', PartnerLastName) AS PartnerLastName, IIF(ISNULL(Organization), '', Organization) AS Organization, " & _
        "Address1, City, State, Zip, Country, Active " & _
 "FROM tblPartner) q " & _
 "WHERE q.IDPartner like '%" & txtPartnerID.Text & "%' AND " & _
 "      q.PartnerFirstName like '%" & txtFirstName.Text & "%' AND " & _
 "      q.PartnerLastName like '%" & txtLastName.Text & "%' AND " & _
 "      q.Organization like '%" & txtOrganization.Text & "%' AND " & _
 "      q.Address1 like '%" & txtStreet.Text & "%' AND " & _
 "      q.City like '%" & txtCity.Text & "%' AND " & _
 "      q.State like '%" & txtState.Text & "%' AND " & _
 "      q.Zip like '%" & txtZipCode.Text & "%' AND " & _
 "      q.Country like '%" & txtCountry.Text & "%' " & _
 "ORDER BY q.IDPartner, q.partnerlastname, q.partnerfirstname", cn)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I solved the issue by running an update query in my DB to update all NULL fields to "". The NULLS where a result of bad data that was brought into the table during the recent rollover to our new system.

Comment: NULL and "" mean two completely different things so simply updating NULL to "" changes the meaning of the data. In your case it _COULD BE_ that "" means "We asked the guy and he says he has no partner" where as NULL _COULD_ mean "Oh crap, we forgot to ask".

Comment: Jeroen,

I get what you are saying and I am aware of the differences between NULL and "". In this case I've been working this DB for 6 years and am redesigning it. While I recognize the difference between the two types "" is more than sufficient for what we are doing here.